# Batch variables not responding

Tags: batch-file

I am making a minesweeper game and I am having trouble with detecting when there is a 0 and 0's around it being showed. For example it would output this:

```
4 
3 
2 
1 0
  a b c d
```

Instead of:

```
4
3 1
2 0 2 1
1 0 0 1
  a b c d
```

Here is my code. The lines to are the ones i am having trouble with. The heading "0tester" is where my problems were.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
title Batch Minesweeper 
color 80
goto define

:define
set setX=1
set setY=1
set testX=1
set testY=1
set plrX=1
set plyY=1
set mines=0
set mineNum=0
set N=
set NE=
set E=
set SE=
set S=
set SW=
set W=
set NW=
set rect1_1= 
set rect2_1= 
set rect3_1= 
set rect4_1= 
set rect5_1= 
set rect1_2= 
set rect2_2= 
set rect3_2= 
set rect4_2= 
set rect5_2= 
set rect1_3= 
set rect2_3= 
set rect3_3= 
set rect4_3= 
set rect5_3= 
set rect1_4= 
set rect2_4= 
set rect3_4= 
set rect4_4= 
set rect5_4= 
set rect1_5= 
set rect2_5= 
set rect3_5= 
set rect4_5= 
set rect5_5= 
set rect6_1= 
set rect7_1= 
set rect8_1= 
set rect9_1= 
set rect6_2= 
set rect7_2= 
set rect8_2= 
set rect9_2= 
set rect6_3= 
set rect7_3= 
set rect8_3= 
set rect9_3= 
set rect6_4= 
set rect7_4= 
set rect8_4= 
set rect9_4= 
set rect6_5= 
set rect7_5= 
set rect8_5= 
set rect9_5= 
set rect1_6= 
set rect2_6= 
set rect3_6= 
set rect4_6= 
set rect5_6= 
set rect6_6= 
set rect7_6= 
set rect8_6= 
set rect9_6= 
set rect1_7= 
set rect2_7= 
set rect3_7= 
set rect4_7= 
set rect5_7= 
set rect6_7= 
set rect7_7= 
set rect8_7= 
set rect9_7= 
set rect1_8= 
set rect2_8= 
set rect3_8= 
set rect4_8= 
set rect5_8= 
set rect6_8= 
set rect7_8= 
set rect8_8= 
set rect9_8= 
set rect1_9= 
set rect2_9= 
set rect3_9= 
set rect4_9= 
set rect5_9= 
set rect6_9= 
set rect7_9= 
set rect8_9= 
set rect9_9= 
set mine1_1=0
set mine2_1=0
set mine3_1=0
set mine4_1=0
set mine5_1=0
set mine1_2=0
set mine2_2=0
set mine3_2=0
set mine4_2=0
set mine5_2=0
set mine1_3=0
set mine2_3=0
set mine3_3=0
set mine4_3=0
set mine5_3=0
set mine1_4=0
set mine2_4=0
set mine3_4=0
set mine4_4=0
set mine5_4=0
set mine1_5=0
set mine2_5=0
set mine3_5=0
set mine4_5=0
set mine5_5=0
set mine6_1=0
set mine7_1=0
set mine8_1=0
set mine9_1=0
set mine6_2=0
set mine7_2=0
set mine8_2=0
set mine9_2=0
set mine6_3=0
set mine7_3=0
set mine8_3=0
set mine9_3=0
set mine6_4=0
set mine7_4=0
set mine8_4=0
set mine9_4=0
set mine6_5=0
set mine7_5=0
set mine8_5=0
set mine9_5=0
set mine1_6=0
set mine2_6=0
set mine3_6=0
set mine4_6=0
set mine5_6=0
set mine6_6=0
set mine7_6=0
set mine8_6=0
set mine9_6=0
set mine1_7=0
set mine2_7=0
set mine3_7=0
set mine4_7=0
set mine5_7=0
set mine7_7=0
set mine8_7=0
set mine9_7=0
set mine1_8=0
set mine2_8=0
set mine3_8=0
set mine4_8=0
set mine5_8=0
set mine6_8=0
set mine7_8=0
set mine8_8=0
set mine9_8=0
set mine1_9=0
set mine2_9=0
set mine3_9=0
set mine4_9=0
set mine5_9=0
set mine6_9=0
set mine7_9=0
set mine8_9=0
set mine9_9=0
goto menu

:menu
color 80
cls
echo Batch Minesweeper
echo.
echo [1] - Play
echo [2] - Info
echo [3] - Exit
echo.
echo Batch Minesweeper made by XXXXXXXXX
choice /c 123 /n /m ""
if %errorlevel%==1 goto play
if %errorlevel%==2 goto info 
if %errorlevel%==3 goto end

:info
cls
echo Each number rebresents how many mines are around it.
pause
echo Every thing else is self explanitory!
pause 
goto menu

:play
cls
color 80
echo Play Menu
echo.
echo [1] - Easy
echo [2] - Medium
echo [3] - Hard
echo [4] - Custom
echo [5] - Back to Menu
choice /c 12345 /n /m ""
if %errorlevel%==1 goto Estartgame
if %errorlevel%==2 goto Mplay
if %errorlevel%==3 goto Hplay
if %errorlevel%==4 goto Cplay
if %errorlevel%==5 goto menu

:Mplay 
cls
echo This game mode is currently univalible.
pause
goto menu

:Hplay
cls
echo This game mode is currently univalible.
pause
goto menu

:Cplay
cls
echo This game mode is currently univalible.
pause
goto menu

:EstartGame
cls
set /a ranX=%RANDOM% * 9 / 32768 + 1
set /a ranY=%RANDOM% * 9 / 32768 + 1
if not %mines%==10 (
    if !mine%ranX%_%ranY%!==0 (
        set mine%ranX%_%ranY%=M
        set /a mines=%mines% + 1
        goto EstartGame
        )
    goto EstartGame
    )
goto Esetup

:Esetup
cls
echo Loading...
set curVal=%setX%_%setY%
if %curVal%==1_10 goto Edisplay
if %setX%==10 (
    set setX=1
    set /a setY=%setY% + 1
    goto Esetup
    )
if !mine%setX%_%setY%!==M (
    set /a setX=%setX% + 1
    goto Esetup
    )
set testX=%setX%
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set N=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
set NE=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set testY=%setY%
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
set E=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
set SE=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set testX=%setX%
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set S=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
set SW=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
set testY=%setY%
set W=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
set NW=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set mineNum=0
if defined N if "%N%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined NW if "%NW%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined W if "%W%"=="M" set/a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined SW if "%SW%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined S if "%S%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined SE if "%SE%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined E if "%E%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined NE if "%NE%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
set mine%setX%_%setY%=%mineNum%
set /a setX=%setX% + 1
goto Esetup

:Edisplay   
cls
echo 9    %rect1_9%    %rect2_9%    %rect3_9%    %rect4_9%    %rect5_9%    %rect6_9%    %rect7_9%    %rect8_9%    %rect9_9%
echo.
echo 8    %rect1_8%    %rect2_8%    %rect3_8%    %rect4_8%    %rect5_8%    %rect6_8%    %rect7_8%    %rect8_8%    %rect9_8%
echo.
echo 7    %rect1_7%    %rect2_7%    %rect3_7%    %rect4_7%    %rect5_7%    %rect6_7%    %rect7_7%    %rect8_7%    %rect9_7%
echo.
echo 6    %rect1_6%    %rect2_6%    %rect3_6%    %rect4_6%    %rect5_6%    %rect6_6%    %rect7_6%    %rect8_6%    %rect9_6%
echo.
echo 5    %rect1_5%    %rect2_5%    %rect3_5%    %rect4_5%    %rect5_5%    %rect6_5%    %rect7_5%    %rect8_5%    %rect9_5%
echo.
echo 4    %rect1_4%    %rect2_4%    %rect3_4%    %rect4_4%    %rect5_4%    %rect6_4%    %rect7_4%    %rect8_4%    %rect9_4%
echo.
echo 3    %rect1_3%    %rect2_3%    %rect3_3%    %rect4_3%    %rect5_3%    %rect6_3%    %rect7_3%    %rect8_3%    %rect9_3%
echo.
echo 2    %rect1_2%    %rect2_2%    %rect3_2%    %rect4_2%    %rect5_2%    %rect6_2%    %rect7_2%    %rect8_2%    %rect9_2%
echo.
echo 1    %rect1_1%    %rect2_1%    %rect3_1%    %rect4_1%    %rect5_1%    %rect6_1%    %rect7_1%    %rect8_1%    %rect9_1%
echo.
echo      a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    j  
set /p inputX="Enter a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h or j and press enter."
set /p inputY="Enter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9 and press enter."
if %inputX%==a set inputX=1
if %inputX%==b set inputX=2
if %inputX%==c set inputX=3
if %inputX%==d set inputX=4
if %inputX%==e set inputX=5
if %inputX%==f set inputX=6
if %inputX%==g set inputX=7
if %inputX%==h set inputX=8
if %inputX%==j set inputX=9
if "!mine%inputX%_%inputY%!"=="M" (
cls
color 40 
echo BOOM, you lose
echo.
pause
cls
set curLVL=E
echo Play again?
pause
goto define
)
if "!mine%inputX%_%inputY%!"=="0" (
set rect%inputX%_%inputY%=0
set setX=%inputX%
set setY=%inputY%
goto 0tester
)
set rect%inputX%_%inputY%=!mine%inputX%_%inputY%!
goto Edisplay 

:0tester
set mbyX=0
set mbyY=0
set testX=%setX%
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set testY=%setY%
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set testX=%setX%
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
set testY=%setY%
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
set rect%testX%_%testY%=0
set mbyX=%testX%
set mbyY=%testY%
)
if "%mbyX%%mbyY%"=="00" goto Edisplay
set setX=%setX%
set setY=%mbyY%
goto 0tester

:end
exit
```

Comment: You should provide a test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when I run it...

Comment: Its not for me... The problem is with the 0tester not working.

Comment: Do you really expect that we analyze your whole code searching for an error we don't understand? This site don't works that way... You may reduce the size of your code managing your [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) via `for` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if !mine%testX%_%testY%!=="0" (
```

Two points on previous line:

- When you compare two values for equality, those values must have the same form, that is, both values must be enclosed in quotes or both not. Otherwise there is no way that `0` be equal to `"0"`.
- If the variable `mine%testX%_%testY%` is not defined, previous line is first *expanded* as `if defined mineX_Y if =="0" (` and *then* parsed, producing an error. The way to fix this error (and also the previous one) is enclosing the variable value in quotes:

.

```
if defined mine%testX%_%testY% if "!mine%testX%_%testY%!"=="0" (
```

This way, if the variable is not defined, the line becomes: `if defined mineX_Y if ""=="0" (` that have correct syntax.